# pass javascript variable into php

Tags: javascript, php

I want to use the javascript variable in php.
When a select option is selected from dropdown it triggers change function and its value is obtained.i want to use this value in php to check the database.

Below is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="application/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){$('select[name="dropdown"]').change(function(){

    var a=$(this).val() ;
        alert(a);



});
});



</script>

</head>

<body>

<select name="dropdown" size=1>
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
</select>
</html>
</body>
```

If Aneyone could help?

Comment: You can make an ajax post request to the backend and check against the database.

Comment: use AJAX [link](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `ajax` like that :-

```
$.post('file.php', {variable: variableToSend});
```

code like that :-

```
    <script type="application/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){$('select[name="dropdown"]').change(function(){

        var a=$(this).val() ;
        $.post('file.php', {variable: a});
    });
});
```

On your server, you would need to receive the variable sent in the post:

```
$variable = $_POST['variable'];
```

Comment: how do i use this variaable in file.php

Comment: get value like that **$variable = $_POST['variable'];**

Comment: i dont want to post the value to any other php file..can it be redirected to the same page with the variable

Comment: change **file.php** on your same page name@rinkusimlai

Comment: i tried its still not working

Comment: its giving undefined variable

Comment: if(isset($_POST['variable'])){  $variable = $_POST['variable'];  }

Comment: try this code for get value